# How do I use C# libraries in Railo?

Tags: c#, coldfusion, railo

I would like to use [MarkdownSharp](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/), a C# library, in my project, but I am not unable to find any information on .Net integration with Railo.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: C++ and C# are two completely different things - running a C# .NET library is not dependant on the C++ CFX functionality. Can you clarify what it is you want to use?

Comment: @Peter, I've update my question... It should probably be two questions, but it's clearer now. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Does it specifically need to be MarkdownSharp? Using [MarkdownJ](http://markdownj.org/) in Railo is easy, but I've no idea if/how different MarkdownSharp and MarkdownJ might be.

Comment: Yeah, I'd definitely say split this into two questions - you can post the URL for each one in the other if they're related, but since each one is asking distinct things, definitely better to have two questions.

Comment: @Peter, the client side implementation I'm using is a JS version of MarkdownSharp. This ensures a level of consistency between in-browser visual feedback and server side parsing.

Comment: Fair enough. Looks like there's also [JMD](http://www.cforcoding.com/2010/01/announcing-jmd-java-markdown-port-of.html), which is a direct Java port of MarkdownSharp, so that might be a better fit ...although it doesn't appear to be actively maintained, so might not be up-to-date. :/

Answer (score 0):

Railo doesn't have the ability to invoke .NET objects. However you could do it via a web service or a web service proxy that you write if one doesnt exist.

Write a .NET webservice that exposes the .NET methods you require, then call this from Railo